# Integration with IdentityServer4 and Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I have created a UI where people can login based on `Azure Active Directory`. The implementation of that was quite easy.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => {
                options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
                options.Domain = "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com";
                options.TenantId = "cc083aa1-XXXX-1bde2c10XXXX";
                options.ClientId = "64a41b3a-XXXX-32e38f03XXXX";
                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
            });
}
```

I'm using this Nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`. Everything is working fine.

Now I want to add roles or custom data to a user. I should add them to a user using `Microsoft Graph` for `Azure B2C`. I did that in the past but I don't wont to change anything in `Active Directory` because the forest is extensive and very complex. If I want to remove any custom data from a user, there are some issues about the replication of that data across the forest.

Then, my idea is to integrate `Azure Active Directory` with `IdentityServer4`. In `IdentityServer4` I can easily add\remove claims and manage users. In the UI I can see now a new button for external login with `AzureAD`.

I expected that the `ExternalLoginCallback` in `AccountController` creates a new user after the successful login. The problem is

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(
                   IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

are both `null`. I have looked around but I'm not be able to find a solution for that.